# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.KeywordLookupSite when running Leiningen

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

I have just downloaded Leiningen but I cannot manage to run it. After downloading its own Jar archive, the script fails with a java error. By running `bash -x lein` I can see that it hangs at this line:

```
+ exec java -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/andrea/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.2.1/clojure-1.2.1.jar -client -Dleiningen.original.pwd=/home/andrea/bin -cp /home/andrea/.clojure/clojure.jar:::::test/:src/:resources/:/home/andrea/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-1.6.2-standalone.jar clojure.main -e '(use '\''leiningen.core)(-main)' /dev/null
```

Which produces:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.KeywordLookupSite.<init>(ILclojure/lang/Keyword;)V
at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:165)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6476)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
```

Interestingly, what fails is not the Java call, but the snippet `'(use '\''leiningen.core)(-main)'`. Running that line without it fires in fact a working clojure REPL. The leiningen-1.6.2-standalone.jar seem to be in the right path. Any ideas? I am new to both Java and Clojure...

Comment: A related issue posted to [CLJ (link)](https://github.com/brentonashworth/sandbar/pull/5), though it's applicable to 1.3

Comment: Related post in SO http://stackoverflow.com/q/7996380/862441

Comment: For anyone else having this problem, here is the solution that worked for me: http://clojure-play-framework.blogspot.com/2012/01/re-new-version-of-clojurescript-one.html

Answer (score 2):

According the the reference [1], you need to add Clojure home to the classpath.

```
echo "export CLOJURE_HOME=$HOME/Opt/clojure
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CLOJURE_HOME" >> $HOME/.profile
```

[1] http://myminutes.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/clojure-lein-gives-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-runtimeexception-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-clojure-lang-keywordlookupsite/

Answer (score 1):

Chui Tey's answer points in the right direction. If, however, you don't have a stand-alone Clojure installation, but instead solely use Leiningen to bootstrap your projects, you should instead add the Leiningen standalone JAR to the classpath.

Thus:

```
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$HOME/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-VERSION-standalone.jar"
```